# UBUNTU 23.10 -network UNCLAIMED

Tags: networking, drivers

After spending (wasting) 5 hours trying to read online how to fix the issue. I still have the problem going. My ethernet port (EIC) is not working and throwing -network UNCLAIMED.

The issue occurred after a reboot where Firmware threw an error saying that the firmware update failed. Then I updated firmware through a USB, though the eth0 is still not working. I am running Ubuntu 23.10

`lshw -c network`

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Ethernet Connection (13) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       version: 11
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:85180000-8519ffff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: b
       bus info: usb@1:11
       logical name: wlx4cedfbb6fd97
       serial: 4c:ed:fb:b6:fd:97
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8822bu driverversion=6.5.0-15-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.17.126 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as a super-user.
```

`cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml`

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
   version: 2
   renderer: NetworkManager
```

`sudo modprobe e1000e`

just gets exectured without and output.

`sudo dmesg | grep e100`

```
[ 0.633990] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver  
[ 0.633991] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.  
[ 0.634010] 1000e 0000:00:1f.6: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)  
[ 0.634189] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[ 0.674683] e1000e: probe of 0000:00:1f.6 failed with error -3
```

UPDATE:
2 weeks later and I still haven't fixed it - Any ideas?

Bios-release-date: 11/06/2023

Comment: What is the response to these terminal commands: `sudo modprobe e1000e` and: `sudo dmesg | grep e100` Please edit your question to add the results. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: `sudo modprobe e1000e` just gets exectured without and output. Where `sudo dmesg | grep e100` gives:

[    0.633990] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver
[    0.633991] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    0.634010] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    0.634189] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    0.674683] e1000e: probe of 0000:00:1f.6 failed with error -3

Comment: Please [edit] your Question to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by both current and future readers (who have better answers).  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.

Comment: Please see: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1576953 Is the result *failed with error -3* the same with a reboot or a cold boot? Is your BIOS/EFI fully updated?

Comment: Firmware was freshly updated and the error remains the same.

Comment: What about a cold boot? Also, does the ethernet start up if you do: `sudo modprobe -r e1000e && sleep 3 && sudo modprobe e1000e`?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the BIOS. The error occured after I got a BIOS update message, saying that I ought to update the BIOS, but I had no connection. I've manually updated it via USB. Also, I've connected WIFI adapter so I have access to network, tho the drivers haven't got resolved. 
@chili555 there was no reaction to that command

Comment: Cold boot doesn't bring anything. 'ifconfig' only displays loopback device
@chili555, yes the error 'failed with error -3' is the same when a reboot or a cold boot